# Greasemonkey replace ckeditor with ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, greasemonkey

On a site I have to use for my work daily, the CKEditor is implemented, but none of the default buttons from CKEditor is visible.
Can I use Greasemonkey to make the default toolbars from CKEditor visible?
That way, I can edit much faster.

Just to clarify. I can't edit the website as I (or any of my colleagues) don't have access to the source thus it must be changed using Greasemonkey.

p.s. Robert, thanks for editing my i to I. i'm not native in English...

Comment: Yes, this can be done with Greasemonkey. No, this question is "Too broad" for Stack Overflow in its current form.

Comment: Can you point me in a direction how i can achieve this? Do i have to load an additional CSS file or another JS file?

Comment: You should look into how the page edits the ckeditor configuration (CKEDITOR.config) and based on the help documentation here (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-toolbar) you can probably just pass in null for the toolbar configuration to load all.